# Sieve of Eratosthenes in Python, looking for a more condensed and correct solution to finding primes

Tags: python, arrays, list, primes

I developed a prime generator using the Sieve of Erasothenes method. Using a list, I eliminate all multiples of 2 up to a user-designated number, continuing with 3, etc. My code is currently giving me a error due to the fact that p2 is being reassigned to the first element of the list indefinitely.

```
n = int(input("What are the primes up to this number?"))
soe = []
for i in range (2, n+1):
    soe.append(i)
for i in range (2, n+1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        soe.remove(i)
    p2 = soe[0]
    holder =1
while p2 < n and holder == 1:
    for i in soe:
        if i % p2 == 0:
            soe.remove(i)
    p2 = soe[0]
print (soe)
```

Comment: Your method of sieving by removing elements from the list instead of just setting them to zero turns out to be very inefficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a simpler and quicker Sieve generator in Python:

```
maxPrime = int(input("What are the primes up to this number?"))
sieve = list(range(maxPrime))
for i in range(2, maxPrime):
    if sieve[i]: # not removed yet = prime!
        print(i)
        for product in range(i, maxPrime, i): # gets i*n for all n up to i*n > maxPrime
            sieve[product] = 0 # marked as not prime
```

The problem in your code is that you always assign `p2=soe[0]`. Additionally, at the end, you print soe, when you have already removed everything from it.

You should print every new p2 you use, including 2, and end the program when soe is empty.

Here is your modified program that is working, with comments:

```
n = int(input("What are the primes up to this number?"))
soe = []
for i in range (2, n+1):
    soe.append(i)
# you can progress straight into sieving out numbers!
while p2 < n and soe: # stop when your list is empty!
    p2 = soe[0]
    print(p2)
    for i in soe:
        if i % p2 == 0:
            soe.remove(i)
# print (soe) # it's going to be empty at the end
```

Comment: Thanks! The code all work and your comments were very useful in getting me to understand what was going on.

Comment: Careful removing from the list as you're looping over it - you'll skip items. I think you may get away with it here due to a fluke in the maths.

Comment: `if i % p2 == 0` will be true every `p2` steps. As @gnibbler and I have said, it makes more sense to zero out the items using a slice-assignment. And you don't have to iterate to `n` -- only to `sqrt(n)`. And `p2` is referenced before it is set. I assume it should be set to 2. Also, this code appears to have `O(n*n)` running time. I would not use it for project Euler questions with `n` greater than 50 000, say.

Comment: If you are using this code for math contests/large numbers, you will find this code too slow. http://pastebin.com/P3BV5vAL It's okay for showing the concepts, though.

Answer (score 2):

I use this:

```
def eras(n):
    last = n + 1
    sieve = [0, 0] + list(range(2, last))
    sqn = int(round(n ** 0.5))
    it = (i for i in xrange(2, sqn + 1) if sieve[i])
    for i in it:
        sieve[i * i:last:i] = [0] * (n // i - i + 1)
    return filter(None, sieve)
```

The real magic is in the slice-assignment in the `for-loop`. It zeroes out the non-primes from `i * i` to `n` in one go.

Answer (score 0):

An large performance improvement (at least for [cpython](http://python.org)) to @icedtrees answer is to set the terms to zero at the C-level using a slice assignment.

```
maxPrime = int(input("What are the primes up to this number?"))
sieve = list(range(maxPrime))
for i in range(2, maxPrime):
    if sieve[i]: # not removed yet = prime!
        print(i)
        sieve[::i] = [0] * len(sieve[::i]) # marked as not prime
```

You can instead use

```
        sieve[i::i] = [0] * ((len(sieve)-1)//i)
```

for the last line if you prefer.

I haven't tried it, but [pypy](http://pypy.org) probably does a decent job of optimising the inner for loop compared to the slice assignment regardless.

Comment: I feel like you should at least credit the original author and offer your suggestion as a (important, if you like) improvement. It's a small point, but just struck me as unscrupulous. I meant nothing personal - I'd be happy to remove the downvote if you edited your answer or referred me to an article/FAQ/rulebook that discourages downvotes for such a reason.